# Masonry with Images Loaded not working on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I am trying to create a clean, full page width Masonry grid layout with Images Loaded. A problem I have encountered is that sometimes there is unwanted space in between grid items. This unwanted space displaces the grid items, causing them to be pushed too far to the right.

Resizing the page instantly makes the problem go away.

This problem doesn't always occur, but consistently occurs when certain number of images of certain dimensions are in the grid.

Furthermore, I realized that I can prevent the unwanted space by making every grid-item equal a set height, however, this is not a viable solution because I do not want the grid-items to have set heights.

Although I've seen many questions posted about Masonry not formatting correctly, none of the answers I've seen have been able to resolve this issue.

I've attached a link to the Codepen below.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#grid").imagesLoaded().done(function () {
    $("#grid").masonry({
      columnWidth: '#grid-sizer',
      itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
body { margin: 0; }

#grid-container { padding: 5px; }
#grid { width: 100%; }
#grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: 100%; }
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) { #grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: calc(100% / 2); } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { #grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: calc(100% / 3); } }
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) { #grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: calc(100% / 4); } }
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) { #grid-sizer, .grid-item { width: calc(100% / 5); } }
.grid-item { padding: 5px; background: blue; }
.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/imagesloaded@4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid-container">
        <div id="grid">
          <div id="grid-sizer"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/200/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/450/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/450/400/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/450/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/450/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/"></div>
          <div class="grid-item"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/300/"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/christophercostello/pen/eRvGLX)

Comment: seems alright to me. does it happen in a particular browser or a specific way you can trigger it?

Comment: Hm, I just checked and I'm only seeing the problem in Chrome.